# How to list non-HD addresses in bitcoin core?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, bip32-hd-wallets

Let's say I imported some private keys, how do I distinguish between those and addresses generated from the HD master key?

Comment: How is that a duplicate?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question